# Google Gusuite Login Issue

Tags: google-workspace, suite

my gsuite account is suspended i am trying to login to my account I am using the same email and password which I used to register into gsuite but now it is giving me error [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNNxd.png)

Answer (score 0):

You must use your G Suite admin account.

In the other hand you can restore the password using the alternative email.